# OneNote Mail Import possible over the API?

Tags: api, email, import, onenote

Does anyone have a clue if it´s possible to Import to OneNote with the API? I recently stumbled upon "me@onenote.com" and my Company would like to implement something like this. 
Could our developers realise this within the OneNote API?
Does the API allow for an Integration into third-party Websites (our WebApplication in this case)?

I would hugely appreciate any help I can get while I´m getting back to reading the documentation!
Thanks a lot to everyone and sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 2):

Import is exactly the sort of scenario that the API covers, yes.  Perhaps you can add some extra depth to your question. Do you want to bulk import a historical cache of email, or import mail as it is sent in some way?

The API uses HTML as its content model, which is likely what your emails can be expressed as anyway.

Take a look at the getting started here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575425.aspx

Comment: Also the me@onenote,com feature uses the OneNote API under the hood:)